# How to use Spin Button and save PDF in one macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I found a way for me to use a spin  button to cycle through a range to make it easier for me to print documents.  I would like to try and combine it with the save PDF macro I already have to make it even faster.

The SpinButton changes the name listed in cell A1 which then dynamically changes all of the data on the worksheet.  The purpose of the SpinButton was to make it easier to cycle through the range.  Same thing with the SavePDF code, I made that so it was easier to print the worksheet than to do it manually.

SpinButton code:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
    If SpinButton1 = 0 Then
    SpinButton1 = Worksheets("Data List").Range("AdvisorNames").Rows.Count
End If
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
 If SpinButton1 = Worksheets("Data List").Range("AdvisorNames").Rows.Count + 1 Then
    SpinButton1 = 1
End If
End Sub
```

SavePDF code:

```
Sub SavePDF()
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="**FILEPATH**" & Range("A1").Value _
, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

The names in the range can vary each month so I'm not sure if it can account for that.  Maybe if there was a popup asking how many times I want to repeat the action?

What I'm trying to find is a way to combine the use  of the spin button and the save pdf code to into one macro.  The spin button updates cell A1, which then dynamically updates the rest of the sheet, and then the Save PDF code save the worksheet to my desktop.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Specifically, it's not clear what the relationship is between the spin button and the `SavePDF` procedure. You've included two event handlers for the spin button, but they're each apparently just assigning an index back to itself. I'd also mention that you probably don't need a spin button (unless you're doing some sort of UI) -- you can "cycle through" (iterate) the cells in a range using a `For Each ...Next` or `For...Next` loop. Ranges can be defined dynamically through the Names manager, or programmatically if needed.

Comment: Sorry about that I edited my post.  Basically I have cell A1 as the name of a person.  I have all of the names in a named range called AdvisorNames.  I use the SpinButton to update the name in A1, which then dynamically updates the entire worksheet.  After that I use the SavePDF macro to save it to my desktop.

It's probably more work than it needs to be but this is just stuff I've cobbled together from stuff I've read online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. I think you will not need spin buttons at all, since you already have the names in a Named Range `"AdvisorNames"`:

```
Sub SaveAllPDFs()

Dim cl as Range, thisName as String

With ActiveSheet
    For Each cl in Worksheets("Data List").Range("AdvisorNames")
        thisName = cl.Value
        .Range("A1").Value = thisName
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="**FILEPATH**" & thisName _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I added the End With at the end at it works perfectly!  Thank you so much David, this is a big help for me.

Comment: Cheers. So this method `For Each` implicitly handles the loop/number of iterations that you wanted to control from another user input, it simply iterates over the cells in the "AdvisorNames" range, and populates A1 accordingly for each.